# How to pass a JSON file in html form and display its content in tabular form [python flask]

Tags: python, flask

Html form takes json file as input

this is my script, I'm able to get the file as input but not able to read it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify, json
import os

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config["FILE_UPLOAD"]=""

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("form.html") 

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if (request.method == 'POST'):
        jf =request.files["file"]
        jf.save(os.path.join(app.config["FILE_UPLOAD"], jf.filename))
        print("file uploaded")
        jdata=json.load(jf)
        response = jsonify(jdata)
    
        
        
        return response
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need save file to local. Jf is io.BytesIO so we only need decode and json.loads to convert to json. Try it:

```
jf =request.files["file"]
data = jf.read().decode("utf8")
jdata = json.loads(data)
return jsonify(jdata)
```